# Add native knitr print methods

Tags: r, knitr, rnotebook

I'm looking for a way to adjust functions which usually show html tables in the viewer or browser in a way that they automatically insert the html in knitr documents like rnotebooks when called.

Specifically I want to change the way functions in the package [sjPlot](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjtbasics/#knitr-integration-of-html-tables) behave. At the moment they return an object with a `$knitr` attribute that has to be inserted manually and then produce an html table in the viewer:

```
`r sjt.frq(efc$e42dep, no.output=TRUE)$knitr`
```

One of these functions is [sjt.frq](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel/blob/master/R/sjTabFrequencies.R). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

From [knit_print](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/knit_print.html):

```
library(knitr)
a = 42
class(a) = "my_class"
knit_print.my_class = function(x,...){
    res = paste("{{", x,"}}")
    asis_output(res)
}
a
```

It works when I knit document but doesn't work with RNotebooks and doesn't work with `sjt.frq`. However with RNotebook works the following statement:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
library(knitr)

data(efc)
asis_output(sjt.frq(efc$e42dep, no.output=TRUE)$knitr)
```

Comment: My experience has been it's best to get the character output and wrap it in `asis_output` as well

Comment: @Benjamin Do you mean `$output.complete` by "character output"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the object. You need a character string of the HTML code. Putting a character string in `asis_output` is the same as putting the same string in `cat` with the chunk option `output='asis'`

Comment: Do you know an example where this works as described above? I just looked up ```DT::datadable``` and if I understand the code correctly they rely on ```htmlwidgets```:

Comment: htmlwidgets::createWidget("datatables", if (hideDataTable) 
    NULL
  else params, package = "DT", width = width, height = height, 
    elementId = elementId, sizingPolicy = htmlwidgets::sizingPolicy(knitr.figure = FALSE, 
      knitr.defaultWidth = "100%", knitr.defaultHeight = "auto"), 
    dependencies = deps, preRenderHook = function(instance) {
      data = instance[["x"]][["data"]]
    ....

Comment: sorry for the triple comment, I don't have enough reputation yet to edit..

Comment: FYI `DT::datatable()` will eventually be converted to a character string and wrapped in `asis_output()`, although the actual implementation is a little complicated. I think it will be great if the author of sjPlot/sjmisc can provide a `knit_print` S3 method, so that its functions "just work" in knitr code chunks, otherwise you will have to either call `asis_output()`, or use `cat()` plus `results='asis'`. If the author needs an example, this email thread may be worth reading: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/knitr/xi0cE6UCb2A/1jb1Jw0EVaQJ